# How do I add an XML attribute, or not, depending on an Option?

Tags: xml, scala

I have written a makeMsg function but I don't like it - it just seems really un-Scala-ish to discriminate based on Option.isDefined. Can you make it better?

```
scala> def makeMsg(t: Option[String]) = 
     | if (t.isDefined) <msg text={t.get} /> else <msg />
makeMsg: (t: Option[String])scala.xml.Elem

scala> makeMsg(Some("hello"))
res0: scala.xml.Elem = <msg text="hello"></msg>

scala> makeMsg(None)
res1: scala.xml.Elem = <msg></msg>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def makeMsg(t: Option[String]) = <msg text={t orNull} />
```

if attribute value is `null` - it will not be added to the element.

### Update

Even better! If you will add this implicit convertion:

```
import xml.Text
implicit def optStrToOptText(opt: Option[String]) = opt map Text
```

you can just use `t` like this:

```
def makeMsg(t: Option[String]) = <msg text={t} />
```

Here is REPL session:

```
scala> import xml.Text
import xml.Text

scala> implicit def optStrToOptText(opt: Option[String]) = opt map Text
optStrToOptText: (opt: Option[String])Option[scala.xml.Text]

scala> def makeMsg(t: Option[String]) = <msg text={t} />
makeMsg: (t: Option[String])scala.xml.Elem

scala> makeMsg(Some("hello"))
res1: scala.xml.Elem = <msg text="hello"></msg>

scala> makeMsg(None)
res2: scala.xml.Elem = <msg ></msg>
```

This works because `scala.xml.UnprefixedAttribute` has constructor that accepts `Option[Seq[Node]]` as value.

Comment: Surely it's simple enough to do this directly that the implicit is just added boilerplate?  `def makeMsg(t: Option[String]) = <msg text={t map Text} />`.  It also feels more type safe, with less risk that you'll be stung by an unanticipated implicit.

Comment: I think it depends on the context. Sure, in this example it's easier to use it directly `text={t map Text}`. But if I, for instance, write some application, that generates a lot of XML, than it makes sense to create `object XmlImplicits` that I will import everywhere and move this kind of boilerplate there.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with this:

```
def makeMsg(t: Option[String]) = t match {
  case Some(m) => <msg text={m} />
  case None => <msg />
}
```

Not as concise as [Easy Angel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777971/how-do-i-add-an-xml-attribute-or-not-depending-on-an-option/4778091#4778091)'s, but it's straight up Scala.

Comment: I think it can be problematic to use this approach if you have several option attributes. But for this simple case it's also ok.

Answer (score 1):

Canonical Scala that does not require the text field to know to cleverly disappear when it's empty:

```
t.map(s => <msg text={s} />).getOrElse(<msg />)
```

You should think about using this pattern whenever you have an option but need to use something that doesn't know about options.  (In this case, Easy Angel has found a more compact solution where it does know about options or something like them.)