# Conditionally include attribute in XML literal

Tags: xml, scala, lift

I have the following XML literal:

```
<input type='radio'
       name={funcName}
       value='true' />
```

I'd like to include `checked='checked'` if `cond` is true.

I've tried this,

```
<input type='radio'
       name={funcName}
       value='true'
       { if (cond) "checked='checked'" else "" } />
```

but it doesn't work.

(I'd *really* like to avoid repeating the whole tag.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add an XML attribute, or not, depending on an Option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777971/how-do-i-add-an-xml-attribute-or-not-depending-on-an-option)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`Option` also works, which reduces unnecessary use of `null`:

```
scala> val checked:Option[xml.Text] = None
checked: Option[scala.xml.Text] = None

scala> val xml = <input checked={checked} />
xml: scala.xml.Elem = <input ></input>
```

Comment: One can also use `opt.orNull` to skip converting to `xml.Text`.

Answer (score 9):

Believe it or not, you can do it like this:

```
<input type='radio'
       name={funcName}
       value='true'
       checked={ if (cond) "checked" else null } />
```

This is one of the dark parts of Scala where `null` actually gets used.

Just to make clear, it does exactly what you want: if `cond` is `false`, then `input` will have *no* `checked` attribute.

Comment: Avoid using null in attribute values.  It causes a fair number of problems in other parts of the 2.8 XML libraries.

Comment: @DavidPollak Are you sure? When checking in the console, it seems the attribute is not created at all in this case.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to add the attribute only when checked, you can add it after using Scala XML API:

```
import scala.xml._

val snippet = {

  val x = <input type='radio'
                 name={funcName}
                 value='true' />

  if( cond ) {
    x % new UnprefixedAttribute("checked","checked",Null)
  } else x

}
```